# ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre "@id" y "@+id"?

Tags: android, android-layout

Al crear una `view`, usamos `@+id/fullname` para identificarlo.

Por ejemplo:

```
<TextView
    android:id = "@+id/tv_fullname"
    android:layout_width = "match_parent"
    android:layout_height = "match_parent"
    android:text = "Fullname" />
```

¿Cuál es la diferencia de usar `@id/tv_fullname`(sin el +), en lugar de `@+id/ tv_fullname`? ¿Es correcto utilizar uno u otro?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**@+id**: indica la definición de un id a un recurso, cuando usamos [`android:id`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:id) también indicamos que se agregue un id de un recurso dentro de `R.java` cuando se compila tu aplicación:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
public static final class id {
    public static final int myButton=0x7f0f009a;
```

Si defines un id a una vista mediante `android:id` y no usas `@+id`, simplemente no será reconocido, por eso es importante usar `@+id`, para definir que es un id el que deseamos asignar y este sea reconocido en tu proyecto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> El signo más (+) antes del tipo de recurso se necesita solo cuando
>   estás definiendo un ID de recurso por primera vez. Cuando compilas la
>   app, las herramientas del SDK usan el nombre del ID para crear un
>   nuevo ID de recurso en el archivo R.java de tu proyecto que hace
>   referencia al elemento EditText. Con el ID de recurso declarado una
>   vez de esta forma, otras referencias al identificador no necesitan el
>   signo más. Es necesario el uso del signo más solo cuando se especifica
>   un nuevo ID de recurso y no se necesita para los recursos concretos,
>   como strings o diseños.

**@id**: indica la referencia de un recurso mediante su id, en realidad se usa para acceder a los recursos definidos en un proyecto, en este caso los que se encuentran en R.java definidos por un identificador:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

es importante mencionar que cuando fue generado el registro del recurso en `R.java` no importa si usas `@id` o `@+id` para obtener la referencia de un recurso.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

Te recomiendo revisar de la documentación:

[Creación de una interfaz de usuario sencilla](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/building-ui.html)

Comment: Gracias por la ejemplificación.

Comment: un placer, saludos.

Answer (score 10):

`@+id` le indica al sistema que genere un nuevo id en la clase `R.java` del projecto. Mientras que
`@id` le indica al sistema que utilize un id ya generado en la clase `R.java`.

Comment: Gracias por responder. +1; En cambio, la respuesta de @jorgesys con la ejemplificación, quedó mejor el entendimiento.